# XSD Schema Validation for 6 or 8 length

Tags: xsd

could anyone please tell me how to specify the validation rule on XSD for scenario below:

> Order number must be exactly either 6 or 8 charater long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsd:simpleType name="orderNumber">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:token">
        <xsd:pattern value="[0-9]{6}|[0-9]{8}"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```